# Finding the SUM of PHP-looped elements + ng-modeling

Tags: php, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I've created a table with a row for each day of the month. Each row has a few input fields for numbers. When someone types in a number, it shows it in within  element to the right of it. I've used a PHP while loop to create multiple rows based on the current day of the month.

What I want to do is make it so that the it adds up the numbers in the  element as the user fills out more rows.

Here's what I have so far, I've put ?????? in the span tags where I've been trying to calculate the totals:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>


<?php 
  date_default_timezone_set('EST'); 
  $day = date(j); 
  $month = date(F); 
?>


<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sales Tracker</h1>
  <div ng-controller="tableCtrl" id="salesTable">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">EDIT</th>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th colspan="3">CORE</th>
          <th colspan="3">ACC</th>
          <th colspan="3">PPP</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $month ?></td>
          <td>TWI</td>
          <td>Actual</td>
          <td>MTD</td>
          <td>Units</td>
          <td>Actual</td>
          <td>MTD</td>
          <td>Units</td>
          <td>Actual</td>
          <td>MTD</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php 
          $i = 1; 
          while ($i <= $day ) { 
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type='checkbox' ng-model='checked$i'>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>$i</span>
                    </td>



                    <!--CORE-->
                    <td>
                        <input type='number' ng-model='twi$i' ng-disabled='!checked$i'>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='number' ng-model='core$i' ng-disabled='!checked$i'>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>{{ ????? }}</span>
                    </td>




                    <!--ACCESSORIES-->
                    <td>
                        <input type='number' ng-model='accUnits$i' ng-disabled='!checked$i'>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='number' ng-model='acc$i' ng-disabled='!checked$i'>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>{{ ????? }}</span>
                    </td>



                    <!--PPP-->
                    <td>
                        <input type='number' ng-model='pppUnits$i' ng-disabled='!checked$i'>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='number' ng-model='ppp$i' ng-disabled='!checked$i'>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>{{ ????? }}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>"; 
              $i++; 
            }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've only been programming for 6 months so layman's terms will not offend.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean fill the sum of the elements in real time? You'll need Javascript for that because it's interface (client-side) and PHP works server-side.

Comment: Yes I know, the PHP was just used to loop and create multiple rows. I cannot figure out how to find the sum using Javascript. Today is the 12th so there's 12 rows and they're labeled "core1, core2, core3 ..., core 12". What is the easiest way to add all of those up using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like overkill to use a library for this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[ng-model^="core"]');
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(elements[i].value);
}
```

Comment: It's showing NaN in the span element. I changed the total to $scope.total. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a common class to all `core` elements:

```
<input type='number' ng-model='core$i' ng-disabled='!checked$i' class='sum_this'>
```

And then in Javascript:

```
function do_sum() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClass('sum_this');
    var total_elements = elements.length;
    var total = 0.0;

    for (var i = 0; i < total_elements; i++) {
        total += parseFloat(elements[i].value);
    }

    alert('The total sum is: ' + total); // Or do something like setting an input value to this
}
```

Or something equivalent.

After doing this, you'll have to attach an event handler when the user releases a key on an input. Those have to have a common class to watch them all at once. Let's say: `watch_this`

```
<input type='number' ng-model='twi$i' ng-disabled='!checked$i' class='watch_this'> <!-- Assuming you want to watch events on this element -->
```

Then:

```
function watch_events() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClass('watch_this');
    var total_elements = elements.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < total_elements; i++) {
        elements[i].onkeyup = do_sum; // Assign the do_sum() function as an event listener
    }
}
```

And, finally, make the script assign the listeners when the DOM has loaded:

```
// When the DOM content is loaded, call watch_events()
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', watch_events, false);
```